# forming a meshgrid with phi values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to make an imshow() diagram with each element showing the value of the polar angle phi (starting from the x-axis). I thought of the following code:

```
x = np.linspace(-3*a,3*a,1000, dtype='complex')
y = np.linspace(-3*a,3*a,1000, dtype='complex')
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
rho = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
phi = np.arcsin(Y/rho)
```

The problem with the last line is that if I just naively use arcsin, arccos or arctan, then the sign will be incorrect in some quadrants. I need phi to vary from 0 to 2*pi, or from -pi to +pi, but with the above code, half of all the values will have the sign incorrect.

So how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.arctan2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html):

```
phi = np.arctan2(Y, X)
```

`phi` will vary between -pi and pi.